# Ugly digits in the reputation pane

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

[image]

Six, three, and four each have different heights. Is it me or is it SO's css to blame?

Comment: Looks like an aliasing issue on your end. I can't imagine those numbers having different styles.

Comment: @Cerbrus - please VTC, I have found the root cause on my side (an ugly typeface).

Comment: Declining, as this is specific to you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem:

The selector is .rep, styled by this stuff in profile.css:

```
.card.rep-card .rep{
    font-size:26px;
    color:#2a2a28;
    padding-top:3px;
    display:inline-block
}
```

The root of the issue is an unlucky combination of typeface and font size.

Nimbus Sans L at some font sizes (22, 28, 42 pt, for instance) gives this ugly effect.